# JSONSerialization swift response is always nil

Tags: swift, xcode, post

I'm performing a post request over my rest api that I built in node. Then the data are stored in a mongodb collection.

This is my code that I use to post the request:

```
    // create dataTask using the session object to send data to the server
let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in

    if let error = error {
        print("Post Request Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return
    }

    // ensure there is valid response code returned from this HTTP response
    guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
        (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode)
    else {
        print("Invalid Response received from the server")
        return
    }

    // ensure there is data returned
    guard let responseData = data else {
        print("nil Data received from the server")
        return
    }

    do {
        // create json object from data or use JSONDecoder to convert to Model stuct
        if let jsonResponse = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: ErrorHandler] {
            print(jsonResponse)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.isLoading = false
                self?.signedIn = true
            }
        } else {
            print("data maybe corrupted or in wrong format")
            throw URLError(.badServerResponse)
        }
    } catch let error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
task.resume()
```

The problem is that the `responseJson` is always `nil`. I tried to perform the same request with `postman` and I get the response correctly. What is the problem? Also because the data are correctly uploaded everywhere.

This is my `postman` result of the same post request.

[image: Postman request]

Comment: Don't use `try?`, replace it with `try` inside a do/catch and print the error and add the output to the question. You can also do `if let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) { print(str) }` and append that output as well

Comment: The response body is not in JSON format.

Comment: I noticed. Now I changed my server code and is working fine. I updated my answer with a correct solution

Comment: So this has been resolved now?